# Push and pop data from array based on checkbox check and uncheck value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var listvalues = []
$('.check').on('change', function() {
  var val = this.checked ? this.value : '';
  listvalues.push(val)
  $('#show').html(listvalues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="1" />1
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="2" />2
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="3" />3
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="4" />4
<div id="show"> </div>
```

I have a code which should push and pop checkbox value based on checkbox check and uncheck, for example if I check and checkbox it should show the value in a div and if I unselect the checkbox the value should disappear from div, and it should not allow anyone to append duplicate data.

But what I did appends even if it is duplicate it appends the data. Can anyone help me on this?

and i wanted to create separate div for each checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `push` & `pop` value from array, you can get all checked values with `listvalues = $('.check:checked').toArray().map(x => x.value);` and display it.

`$('.check:checked')` will only return `.check` which are `checked`. Then `.toArray()` will convert `jquery` object into `array` & get use `.map(x => x.value)` to fetch only value from checked elements.

```js
var listvalues = []
$('.check').on('change', function() {
  listvalues = $('.check:checked').toArray().map(x => x.value).join(', ');
  $('#show').html(listvalues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="1" />1
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="2" />2
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="3" />3
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="4" />4
<div id="show"> </div>
```

Comment: yeah this works fine , but is there any way i can create seperate div for each checkbox selected , because here my data gets appended like without a space

Comment: You can use `.join(', ');` to append values form array with separator as `, ` .

Answer (score 0):

To remove you can use `filter` to exclude the unchecked item. I'm not sure what you want to achieve with different divs, please explain.

```js
var listvalues = []
$('.check').on('change', function() {
    if(this.checked){
        listvalues.push(this.value);
    }
    else {
        listvalues = listvalues.filter(item => item != this.value);
    }

    $('#show').html(listvalues.sort());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="1" />1
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="2" />2
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="3" />3
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="4" />4
<div id="show"> </div>
```

Comment: but is there any way i can create seperate div for each checkbox selected , because here my data gets appended like without a space

Comment: @AuroraEugene That's the part I want to understand. Separate them how? More space between the checkboxes or spaces between the output data? Maybe create a dummy output you are looking for.

Comment: like there should be space between data